# Powershell Script to read last received emails

Tags: powershell, loops, outlook, where-clause, break

I have a huge mailbox I run a script on everyday to catch emails with certain line in their body and mine information from them. The script basically pipes Inbox items into a "`where`" command, which I am employing my conditions such as received date.
Here's the problem. This method goes through all the emails in the mailbox, which takes up to 10 minutes sometimes, while I receive only up to 20 new emails everyday and want to check only those emails that are sent the last e.g. 7 days ago. Is there any way to break a "`Where`" loop (if we can even call it a loop)? should I change my method to a `for` loop with `if` condition, or a `break`? is there a best way you can suggest to only read and pick emails that were sent to me (or received by me) the last 7 days? This is what it is looking like atm:

```
$Inbox.Items | where{$_.body.startswith('text') -AND !($_.Categories.StartsWith('Script,')) -AND $_.ReceivedTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
ForEach-Object {some action}
```

Comment: Where does `$Inbox` come from. Are you using the Outlook Object Model's COM interface?  If you were using EWS Management API I'd say you could search for it, get back a much smaller result set, etc... That said if you're forced to go through OOM's items collection then yes, use 1 of the `ForEach` constructs and `break` when ready

Comment: If it's looping in the Inbox, can you move the emails *older* than a week into a subfolder that isn't scanned (or, any email, once parsed, moved into the subfolder)? This way it won't take any longer than it needs to, you can be sure it runs quickly, and you get some minor organisation in there too?